# I want to replace commas (,) with underscores (_) in all links from the subdomain img.domain.com in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to replace commas (,) with underscores (_) in all links from the subdomain img.domain.com in nginx, specifically like this:
From:
https://img.domain.com/images/w_1048,h_589/f_webp,q_auto/hinhanh.png
To:
https://img.domain.com/images/w_1048_h_589/f_webp_q_auto/hinhanh.png
How can I do that?
I tried to use sub_filter but not successful.
My system: Ubuntu, nginx, WordPress.
Thanks!